# Why am i getting Sonarqube 'License Corrupted' error?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I am getting 'License for vbnet is corrupted' error, while running analysis on vb.net project . Can you please help why am i getting this error ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased a valid license and it should still be valid you can try to re-enter the key you purchased. The next best thing you can do is contacting [SonarSource](https://www.sonarsource.com/company/contact). You must at least mention the SonarQube and the VB plugin version.

Comment: I am using sonar scanner for MSbuild 4.3.1 and sonarqube version 7.2